# Google Analytics HTTP status -1 when sending hit(s) by request [GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:response:data:error:]

Tags: objective-c, google-analytics

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"ui_action"
                                                      action:@"button_press"
                                                       label:@"play"
                                                       value:nil] build]];
```

When I send the event, I get log:

> 2017-06-20 11:30:00.541 Right-iOS[28240:626691] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.17 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:response:data:error:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:226): Hit(s) dispatched: HTTP status -1

Comment: i get the reason. http status -1 because i use simulator, when i use device the http status 200. thanks